# In linux, how do you get a total size of a folder for files that are 1MB and up

Tags: linux, command-line, ls

Hi im doing some cleaning up on my server and i want to know how would i get the total size of a folder of files that are 1mb and up and also 1mb and below. I got as far as:

```
ls -lh | grep 'M '
```

But i can't get the total size of everything.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of parsing the output of `ls` (which is considered really bad practice<sup>†</sup>), you could use `find` and `du` as so:

- To find all files (`-type f`) in current directory and subdirectories of size ≥1M (`-size +1M`), and get the sum of their sizes:

  ```
  find . -type f -size +1M -print0 | du -sch --files0-from=- | tail -1
  ```
- Similar, but do not recurse in subdirectories (`-maxdepth 1`):

  ```
  find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -size +1M -print0 | du -sch --files0-from=- | tail -1
  ```
- For files of size ≤1M:

  ```
  find . -type f -size -1M -print0 | du -sch --files0-from=- | tail -1
  find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -size -1M -print0 | du -sch --files0-from=- | tail -1
  ```

This works provided your version of `du` supports the `--files0-from` option.
If not, you could try this:

```
find . -type f -size +1M -exec du -sch {} + | tail -1
```

but if you have too many files, it won't work (you'll get a wrong answer)! In this case, you could try this instead:

```
find . -type f -size +1M -exec sh -c 'du -sch "$@" | tail -1' _ {} +
```

you'll then have several lines (hopefully not too many) and you'll have to do the math yourself.

With `find` you have a complete control on which files you want to consider! it's filtering possibilities are mostly endless.

Cheers!

---

<sup>†</sup>  You will get wrong answers with `ls -1h | grep 'M '` in case you have files that contain the string `"M "`. And the output of `ls` is to be read by humans, not machines... machines have other much better means to obtain this kind of information.

Comment: +1 for a nice answer with explanations. I just would like to add one other option:  find /path/to/search -type f -size +1M -ls | awk '{ SUM += $2} END {print SUM}'

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me.

```
ls -lh | grep 'M' | awk '{ SUM += $5} END {print SUM}'
```

Comment: what is the $5 stand for and how do you derive it? by the spaces in between words?

Comment: $5 is the fifth field of the `ls -l` output. (Which is the file size). Parsing ls output is considered bad form though and it will break if ls ever changes. Using find -ls does the same and is considered a better solution. And that can be combined with the -type f while using subdirectories.